# Trying to add a start screen to a game

Tags: javascript

Using references from a YouTube video, I was able to make a snake game, using JavaScript. I was able to modify it so there would be levels. For some reason, I can't seem to add a start screen to the game.

It either crashes, or goes right though. Could anyone help?

Attached is the game. 
Trying to learn from this, thanks!

```
// Constants
var COLS=26, ROWS=26
// IDs
var EMPTY=0, SNAKE=1, FRUIT=2
// Directions
var LEFT=0, UP=1, RIGHT=2, DOWN=3
// Game objects
var canvas, ctx, keystate, frames, score, lvl;
//KeyCodes
var Key_LEFT=37, Key_UP=38, Key_RIGHT=39, Key_DOWN=40, Key_ENTER=13
// Current level
var gs = 5

var grid = {

    width: null,
    height: null,
    _grid: null,

    init: function(d, c, r) {
        this.width = c;
        this.height = r;

        this._grid = [];
        for (var x=0; x < c; x++) {
            this._grid.push([]);
            for (var y=0; y < r; y++) {
                this._grid[x].push(d);
            }
        }

    },

    set: function(val, x, y) {
        this._grid[x][y] = val;
    },

    get: function(x, y) {
        return this._grid[x][y];
    }
}

var snake = {

    direction: null,
    last: null,
    _queue: null,

    init: function (d, x, y){
        this.direction = d;

        this._queue = [];
        this.insert(x, y);
    },

    insert: function (x, y) {
        this._queue.unshift({x:x, y:y});
        this.last = this._queue[0];
    },

    remove: function () {
        return this._queue.pop();
    }
}


function setFood() {
    var empty = [];

    for (var x=0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for (var y=0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            if (grid.get(x, y) === EMPTY) {
                empty.push({x:x, y:y});
            }
        }
    }

var randpos = empty[Math.round(Math.random()*(empty.length - 1))];
    grid.set(FRUIT, randpos.x, randpos.y);
}

function main() {
    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = COLS*20;
    canvas.height = ROWS*20;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    ctx.font = "12px Helvetica";

    frames = 0;
    keystate = {};

    // keeps track of the keyboard input
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
        keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
    });
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(evt) {
        delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
    });

    startGameScreen();

    init();
    loop();

}

function startGameScreen() {

    do {
        ctx.font = "25px Helvetica";
        drawStartScreen();
        update();
        if ([Key_DOWN]) {
            alert("You pressed a key");
        }
    } while (onKeyDown !== true);
}

function drawStartScreen() {

    var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
    var th = canvas.height/grid.height;

    for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
                case EMPTY:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    break;
                case SNAKE:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                    break;
                case FRUIT:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                    break;
            }
            ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
        }
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillText("Press Enter To Start", canvas.width - 380, canvas.height / 2);



}

function init() {

    score = 0;
    lvl = 1;
    gs = 5;
    grid.init(EMPTY, COLS, ROWS);

    var sp = {x:Math.floor(COLS/2), y:ROWS-1};
    snake.init(UP, sp.x, sp.y );
    grid.set(SNAKE, sp.x, sp.y);

    setFood();
}

function loop() {
    update();
    draw();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(loop, canvas);
}

function update() {
    frames++;

    if (keystate[Key_LEFT] && snake.direction !== RIGHT) {
        snake.direction = LEFT;
    }
        if (keystate[Key_UP] && snake.direction !== DOWN) {
        snake.direction = UP;
    }
        if (keystate[Key_RIGHT] && snake.direction !== LEFT) {
        snake.direction = RIGHT;
    }
        if (keystate[Key_DOWN] && snake.direction !== UP) {
        snake.direction = DOWN;
    }



    if (score > 40) {
        lvl++
        gs--
        score = 0

    }


    if (frames%gs === 0) {

        var nx = snake.last.x;
        var ny = snake.last.y;

        switch (snake.direction) {
            case LEFT:
                nx--;
                break;
            case UP:
                ny--;
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                nx++;
                break;
            case DOWN:
                ny++;
                break;
        }

        if (0 > nx || nx > grid.width-1  ||
            0 > ny || ny > grid.height-1 ||
            grid.get(nx, ny) === SNAKE
        ) {
            return init();
        }

        if (grid.get(nx, ny) === FRUIT) {   
            var tail = {x:nx, y:ny};
            score = score + 10;
            setFood();
        } else {
            var tail = snake.remove();
            grid.set(EMPTY, tail.x, tail.y);
            tail.x = nx;
            tail.y = ny;
        }


        grid.set(SNAKE, nx, ny);

        snake.insert(nx, ny);

    }

}

function draw() {
    var tw = canvas.width/grid.width;
    var th = canvas.height/grid.height;

    for (var x = 0; x < grid.width; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < grid.height; y++) {
            switch (grid.get(x, y)) {
                case EMPTY:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    break;
                case SNAKE:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#0ff";
                    break;
                case FRUIT:
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#f00";
                    break;
            }
            ctx.fillRect(x*tw, y*th, tw, th);
        }
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillText("SCORE: " + score, 10, canvas.height - 10);

    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillText("Level: " + lvl, canvas.width-50, canvas.height - 10); 



}
```

Comment: provide jsfiddle demo please

Comment: Im not sure what that means, sorry.

Comment: Is this what you meant?

http://jsfiddle.net/hLsk2yss/

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve from your code

Comment: Im trying to stop the game from initialing, and having it wait for the user to press enter before it starts